# nativeElement.select() not working on input when used in ngAfterViewInit()

Tags: javascript, angular, data-binding, settimeout, ngmodel

I am trying to set focus() and select() on input text in ngAfterViewInit() in angular ,but it doesn't select the input text.But If I use it with setTimeout() it works

Code

```
component.html

<input [(ngModel)]="inputName" #inputtext />

component.ts-

export class Test implements AfterViewInit{

    private _inputName:string;

    @ViewChild("inputtext") private _inputTextbox: ElementRef;

    constructor(){
        this._inputName="someText";
    }

    public get inputName():string{
        return this._inputName;
    }

    public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this._inputTextbox.nativeElement.focus();
        this._inputTextbox.nativeElement.select();
    }
}
```

I was expecting that it should focus and select the input text once input textbox is visible.
For above code,if I use setTimeout to focus and select ,it works.

Comment: Hi, you should check your template (html file), there might be another element that's focused by default. Check which element it is, it might give you a hint.

Comment: Hi @Vazgen ,input gets focussed but the text in input doesn't get selected.I want the text to get selected by itself initially